# Posting response to google form

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-forms

I'm trying to send a response from a Unity app to a google form, after following pretty much every tutorial available for c#, I came to the conclusion that all of them are now outdated since every webrequest I make returns error 401 unauthorized access.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, it was as simple as making sure your google form doesn't have any question that requires a google account, for example in my case I needed to upload an image and that required the user to sign up, therefore all requests without credentials will return error 401